# Json Items duplicating when using a foreach loop

Tags: c#, json, loops

I am currently creating an application that generates a JSON file based on text the user types in. When the application generates the JSON file, specific items duplicate. I know there is something wrong with my code, I just can't figure out what.

**Entire Class:**

```
private readonly List<Tuple<string, List<Engine.Swap>>> parentAssetTup = new();
private readonly List<Tuple<string, string>> searchReplace = new();

public void CompileThis()
{
    foreach (var searchTB in searches)
        foreach (var reaplceTB in replaces)
            searchReplace.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(searchTB.Text, reaplceTB.Text));

    List<Engine.Swap> swaps = new();
    List<Engine.Asset> assets = new();

    foreach (var item in searchReplace)
        swaps.Add(new Engine.Swap(item.Item1, item.Item2));

    foreach (var paTB in parentAssets)
        parentAssetTup.Add(new Tuple<string, List<Engine.Swap>>(paTB.Text, swaps));

    foreach (var i in parentAssetTup)
        assets.Add(new Engine.Asset(i.Item1, i.Item2));

    Engine.Root root = new(itemTypeTB.Text,
                           typeTB.Text, 
                           nameTB.Text, 
                           iconTB.Text, 
                           overrideIconTB.Text, 
                           assets);
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new();
    fbd.Tag = "Select an output path.";
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        Engine.Compile(root, fbd.SelectedPath);
    else
    {
        string defaultPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        Engine.Compile(root, defaultPath);
    }
}
```

Engine class added back because of edit suggestion.
**Engine Class:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PlatoPluginEngine.Classes;

internal class Engine
{
    internal class Swap
    {
        public Swap(string search, string replace)
        {
            this.search = search;
            this.replace = replace;
        }

        public string search { get; }
        public string replace { get; }
    }

    internal class Asset
    {
        public Asset(string parentasset, List<Swap> swaps)
        {
            this.parentasset = parentasset;
            this.swaps = swaps;
        }

        public string parentasset { get; }
        public List<Swap> swaps { get; }
    }

    internal class Root
    {
        public Root(string itemtype,
                    string type,
                    string name,
                    string icon,
                    string overrideicon,
                    List<Asset> assets)
        {
            this.itemtype = itemtype;
            this.type = type;
            this.name = name;
            this.icon = icon;
            this.overrideicon = overrideicon;
            this.assets = assets;
        }

        public string itemtype { get; }
        public string type { get; }
        public string name { get; }
        public string icon { get; }
        public string overrideicon { get; }
        public List<Asset> assets { get; }
    }

    public static void Compile(Root root, string path)
    {
        string plugin = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);

        File.WriteAllText($@"{path}\PlatoPlugin.json", plugin.ToString());
    }
}
```

When I say Json items duplicate I mean:

I have the program formatted like this:
ItemType,
Type,
Name,
Icon,
Override Icon,

After these static members,
The user can choose to dynamically add options, these options are:
Parent asset,
Search,
Replace,

When the user generates the JSON file with all of the input data, the JSON output is:

```
{
  "itemtype": "IT",
  "type": "T",
  "name": "N",
  "icon": "I",
  "overrideicon": "OI",
  "assets": [
    {
      "parentasset": "PA1",
      "swaps": [
        {
          "search": "S1",
          "replace": "R1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parentasset": "PA1",
      "swaps": [
        {
          "search": "S1",
          "replace": "R1"
        },
        {
          "search": "S1",
          "replace": "R1"
        },
        {
          "search": "S1",
          "replace": "R2"
        },
        {
          "search": "S2",
          "replace": "R1"
        },
        {
          "search": "S2",
          "replace": "R2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The output expected(based on the given user input) is:

```
{
  "itemtype": "IT",
  "type": "T",
  "name": "N",
  "icon": "I",
  "overrideicon": "OI",
  "assets": [
    {
      "parentasset": "PA1",
      "swaps": [
        {
          "search": "S1",
          "replace": "R1"
        },
        {
          "search": "S2",
          "replace": "R2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The foreach loops that are malfunctioning are:

```
foreach (var item in searchReplace)
            swaps.Add(new Engine.Swap(item.Item1, item.Item2));
foreach (var i in parentAssetTup)
            assets.Add(new Engine.Asset(i.Item1, i.Item2));
```

The values used here are just placeholder values.
As you can see, the items are duplicates.

I am using Newtonsoft for my JSON serializer. The project was made with .Net 6.0
If you need any more info please don't hesitate to ask!
Please help.

Comment: Why do you mean by "duplicate"? Can you give a specific example?

Comment: @KlausGütter I updated the question, to be more precise, I also updated the classes to the ones I am currently using. I apologize for any vagueness.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted nearly 200 lines of code here - it would really help if you'd narrow this down to a [mcve]. I'd start by removing the user interface aspects entirely - I'd expect to be able to reproduce this programmatically by just creating some objects, setting their properties appropriately with hard-coded data, then generating the JSON. The [mcve] would then include the actual output and the expected output. It should be complete (ideally so we could run it ourselves) but also minimal - remove everything you can that isn't needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I removed the unnecessary code bits, and left the parts that deal with the serialization. I have hard coded the data and that works fine, the problem is automating the process, something is wrong with the foreach loops, I just don't know what.

Comment: "I have hard coded the data and that works fine" - that would suggest the problem isn't the serialization then. Have you looked at the data in the debugger after populating it? I'd expect you to be able to see the duplication there. I'm afraid without being able to reproduce it ourselves, this is going to be hard to sort out. (It still doesn't look minimal to me, either - do we need the "parent assets" part to see the problem? Do we need all the properties like name, icon and overrideicon?

Comment: @JonSkeet I removed the engine class since I know that is not the issue, The parameters for the "Engine.Root" constructor are necessary due to their role in the json file. The items seem to duplicate while going through one of the foreach loops, I just don't know which one, or why it is happening.

Comment: Again, stepping through in a debugger should help you determine that, along with simplifying. It doesn't help that it's still not clear what you'd *expect* the result to be for your JSON. You say "the items are duplicates" - which ones are you concerned about? The swaps? The fact that there are two assets? The question really isn't clear enough for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the expected output along with the foreach loops that are malfunctioning. The items that are duplicating are the swaps and the parentassets. The first parentasset only contains one swap when it should have two(using the given user input), and the parentasset gets duplicated which should not be happening.

Comment: My guess is that CompileThis is being called twice. That would certainly explain everything. You should be able to detect that with logging, or in the debugger. But I'm afraid without being able to reproduce this I don't think I can help any further.

Comment: Alright Well, thank you for your time.